# Initiating a loop through a keypress makes unwanted infinite loop (Python)

Tags: python

I'm attempting to make a program where every time I press "r", the "c" key will be pressed for 1.03 seconds.

I've found that the following code will press the "c" key for 1.03 seconds:

```
import keyboard
import time

end = time.time() + 1.03
while time.time() < end:
    keyboard.press("c")
```

In order to run the code above upon the pressing of "r", I wrote this:

```
while True:
    
    if keyboard.is_pressed("r"):

        end = time.time() + 1.03
        while time.time() < end:
            keyboard.press("c")
```

This causes "c" to be pressed infinitely.

I can't wrap my head around it, which makes me mad because I know it must be a simple error.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Exactly what third-party `keyboard` module are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never break the outside while loop so if you press and release r it will run your inner while loop then go back to the outside while loop.

I would suggest the keyboard.on_press_key() (see [docs](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard#keyboard.on_press_key)) function instead of checking is_pressed.

Comment: Not breaking means that you can press r several times in order to see the c key also pressed.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean to release the key afterwards?

```py
while True:
    
    if keyboard.is_pressed("r"):

        end = time.time() + 1.03
        while time.time() < end:
            keyboard.press("c")
        keyboard.release(“c”)
```